# Can you append to multiple lists at once in python?

Tags: list, python-3.x

Say I have the list:

```
mylist=[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 6 , 7, 8, 9]
```

and 9 empty lists:

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
list3=[]
```

and so on..
Is there a way of using a for loop to append mylist[0] to list1, mylist[1] to list2 etc. for all 9 items, or do I have to code for each of them separately?

Comment: you can do it if you have all of your lists in a data structure ! like list or tuple , but there is no need to define all of the empty lists an waste the memory you can just use a `dictionary`

Comment: Having so many distinct, numbered variables seems wrong. What are you doing with all those lists?

Comment: [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at trying to use a dictionary or something. They contain scores for 9 different rounds.

Comment: I ended up using a list of lists. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is a fairly simple way of appending to multiple lists at once.

```
list1, list2, list3 = [], [], []
my_list = [1,2,3]

[x.append(y) for x,y in zip([list1, list2, list3], my_list)]
```

### Output

list1 = [1]

list2 = [2]

list3 = [3]

Comment: It is worth noting that by running your code we receive a `listcomp` with `None` values only. However, when calling variables by original names - we receive correct values.

Comment: Yes of course, the list comprehension itself doesn't return anything because it is simply appending things to another list.

Comment: Yeah but at first I thought your solution is incorrect - that's why I decided to add this comment. It may be useful (especially for beginners). By the way, the first line can be shortened to `tuple([] for _ in range(3))`.

Comment: It is a bad coding style to use a list comprehension for side-effects (like your code). List comprehensions are used to build lists. You should use a usual `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems you want the first number in list1, the second in list2, and so on. I assumed you wanted to loop around, returning to list1. The result being {0: [9, 6, 7], 1: [8, 5, 8], 2: [7, 6, 9]}

```
mylist=[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 6 , 7, 8, 9]

lists = {0:[], 1:[], 2:[]}

counter = 0
size = len(lists)
for x in mylist:
    lists[counter % size].append(x)
    counter+= 1
```

Comment: No, that's not what I wanted - I did say I have 9 empty lists to append to. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with the same logic as in the [answer by Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59575325/320437) but this one does not misuse list comprehension to do things it was not designed for:

```py
list1, list2, list3 = [], [], []
my_list = [1, 2, 3]

destination_lists = [list1, list2, list3]
for destination_list, item in zip(destination_lists, my_list):
    destination_list.append(item)

print(list1, list2, list3)
```

Output:

```
[1] [2] [3]
```

---

List comprehensions were designed to build lists, not to perform side-effects like `x.append(y)` in the ALi's answer.